# Php Smarty: how to scrape & embed a youtube video by keyword?

Tags: php, youtube, embed, smarty, keyword

please could someone let me see some examples? Really Thank You.
I found something but now i have another problem:
for example i have the following javascript inside a tpl:

```
    <script src="http://www.domain.com/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="youtubeDiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
insertVideos({'block':'youtubeDiv','q':'keyword','type':'search','results':8,'order':'most_relevance','player':'embed','layout':'thumbnails'});</script>
```

between {literal}{/literal} to let it work... but how to replace the "keyword" with the smarty variable {$product.name} ???

Comment: What it has to do with Smarty?

Comment: what do you mean? i would to know how to do this with smarty... i'm using that... or can i integrate in other way?

Comment: i need it inside a .tpl file...

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved... in place of 'keyword':

```
'{/literal}{$mySmarty_variable}{literal}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form onsubmit="insertVideos({'block':'youtubeDivSearch','type':'search','q':document.getElementById('ytSearchField').value,'results': 20,'order':'most_relevance','layout':'thumbnails'}); return false;">
    <input id="ytSearchField" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="  Search  " />
</form>

<div id="youtubeDivSearch"></div>

<script src="http://www.yvoschaap.com/ytcp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.1/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div id="youtubeDiv"></div>
<div id="youtubeDivUser"></div>

<script>insertVideos({'block':'youtubeDivUser','type':'user','q':'','results': 20,'layout':'thumbnails','player':'embed','imgstyle':'3px solid #333'});</script>
```